# How to use cwac-saferoom with SecretKey

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

Is there any way with cwac-saferoom to use `SafeHelperFactory` with a generated `java.security.Key` coming from Android KeyStore ?

Comment: I do not know whether that is an appropriate use of `Key`. You could use the `AndroidKeyStore` to encrypt a file that contains a generated key, though.

Comment: BTW, your question really has much more to do with SQLCipher for Android. SafeRoom is simply an API layer on top of that. You might consider posting your question [on the Zetetic support board](https://discuss.zetetic.net/c/sqlcipher).